# Jquery datatable sort date in French

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs, datatables-1.10

I use this link as an example. http://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

I try to sort the date column in French but it doesn't sort it correctly. 
It looks like it doesn't understand the French format. If I change to English date and use the default locale (english), then it works properly.

The following is what I tried. Please let me know what I did wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

moment.locale('fr', {
        months : "janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre".split("_"),
        monthsShort : "janv._févr._mars_avr._mai_juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.".split("_"),
        weekdays : "dimanche_lundi_mardi_mercredi_jeudi_vendredi_samedi".split("_"),
        weekdaysShort : "dim._lun._mar._mer._jeu._ven._sam.".split("_"),
        weekdaysMin : "Di_Lu_Ma_Me_Je_Ve_Sa".split("_"),
        longDateFormat : {
            LT : "HH:mm",
            LTS : "HH:mm:ss",
            L : "DD/MM/YYYY",
            LL : "D MMMM YYYY",
            LLL : "D MMMM YYYY LT",
            LLLL : "dddd D MMMM YYYY LT"
        },calendar : {
            sameDay: "[Aujourd'hui à] LT",
            nextDay: '[Demain à] LT',
            nextWeek: 'dddd [à] LT',
            lastDay: '[Hier à] LT',
            lastWeek: 'dddd [dernier à] LT',
            sameElse: 'L'
        },
        relativeTime : {
            future : "dans %s",
            past : "il y a %s",
            s : "quelques secondes",
            m : "une minute",
            mm : "%d minutes",
            h : "une heure",
            hh : "%d heures",
            d : "un jour",
            dd : "%d jours",
            M : "un mois",
            MM : "%d mois",
            y : "une année",
            yy : "%d années"
        },
        ordinalParse : /\d{1,2}(er|ème)/,
        ordinal : function (number) {
            return number + (number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème');
        },
        meridiemParse: /PD|MD/,
        isPM: function (input) {
            return input.charAt(0) === 'M';
        },
        // in case the meridiem units are not separated around 12, then implement
        // this function (look at locale/id.js for an example)
        // meridiemHour : function (hour, meridiem) {
        //     return /* 0-23 hour, given meridiem token and hour 1-12 */
        // },
        meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
            return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
        },
        week : {
            dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
            doy : 4  // The week that contains Jan 4th is the first week of the year.
        }
    });



      moment.locale('fr');

    $.fn.dataTable.moment('d MMM yyyy','fr');
    $('.testtable').dataTable();
});
```

Here is the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/9gohzd9t/71/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates in your data table do not pass the `isValid()` check. Your current format is `D MMM yyyy`. In this format `yyyy` should be replaced with `YYYY`. Upper case is the correct notation here.

Secondly, the month notation you have does not pass the strict `isValid()` test. Two possible solutions:

1. Remove the dot after the short month abbreviations. For example `janv` instead of `janv.`

   Your table would be:

   ```
   <table class="testtable">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Date</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>12 mars 2001</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>1 janv 2015</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>1 févr 2014</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

   See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gohzd9t/74/) for a minimal example.
2. Modify the plugin to remove the strict criteria, and adding the dot to your format.

   The modified part of the plugin:

   ```
   // Removed true as the last parameter of the following moment
   return moment( d, format, locale ).isValid() ?
       'moment-'+format :
   null;
   ```

   Your new format:

   ```
   $.fn.dataTable.moment('D MMM. YYYY','fr');
   ```

   See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gohzd9t/76/) for an example of this.